# Copy byte* to char array goes wrong

Tags: c++, arduino-esp8266

How does the copy of char array work?
When I copy the byte array to a char array something went wrong.
I have the following code:

```
void onIncomingMQTT_CMD(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
   char a[length];
   int i;
   String s = "";
   for(i=0; i<length; i++) {
      a[i] = (char)payload[i];
      s = s + (char)payload[i];
   }
   //message_buff[i] = '\0';
   logToMQTT(s + "[payload]");
   a[i] = '\0';
   logToMQTT(a);


   char b[length];
   int j;
   String d = "";
   for(j=0; j<length; j++) {
      b[j] = (char)payload[j];
      d = d + (char)payload[j];
   }
   //message_buff[j] = '\0';
   logToMQTT(d + "[payload2]");
   b[j] = '\0';
   logToMQTT(b);
```

I expected that the array `a` and `b` would be the same. But in the log output I see that the first `[payload]` is correct. But the second `[payload2]` is different. It show chars from the topic.

```
ON[payload]
we[payload]
```

What is wrong with the copy from `byte` array to `char` array?

Comment: Are you sure this isn't actually C++? Because this code won't work in C.

Comment: When the copying loops are finished, then `i` (and `j` for the second loop) will be equal to `length`. And as array indexes are based on zero, the last valid index in the arrays `a` and `b` are `length - 1`. Which means your string terminator will be written out of bounds. If you want to have strings, why don't use use the `String` class for `a` and `b` as well?

Comment: why not s+=(char)payload[i];?Also i don't think char a[length]; is a good practice, i would use malloc for that.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: The funktion logToMQTT is the problem. I found in the docu that the MQTT library uses the same buffer for in and out going Messages. So it gets confused when sending mqtt message while in call back reciving function. Thanks for the help. I also Change to malloc for allocating a char*